# Background image aligned at bottom even when resized

Tags: css

I'm trying to align an image at the bottom of my DIV, which happens to be the background. Just to make the case even more real, I also added some overlay (as that is how I am doing it in my project).

https://jsfiddle.net/jy0w2jmr/

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

That will make the background size 100% of the DIV, but not stretched out, so it will be 300px tall (if my DIV is 300px tall).

How do I make it, so when I resize the DIV, the background image also resizes, but sticks to the bottom of the DIV and NEVER overflows the DIV? `background-position: bottom;` does not seem to stick it to the bottom of my DIV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg");

    position: relative;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg");
   
    position: relative;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes, `contain` as the background-size works. I forgot about that value! Thanks.